# Git clone with sudo -u without passphrase

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I have user - `dev` with ssh config like this:

```
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If I login as this dev user (sudo su dev) and try to clone, everything works fine. Clone used without passphrase.

But when I use command like this:

```
sudo -u dev git clone repositoryurlhere
```

I always see:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

How to get rid of this?

Comment: Can you check the first few lines of `/home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa` to see if it contains `Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED`?

Comment: @NilsWerner yep, file contains `Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `/home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa` is encrypted. You probably had to enter a passphrase a few minutes agon when you were still `dev`, but forgot you did. After entering the password your keychain usually remembers it for a few minutes (similar to `sudo`, you need to enter your password only every few minutes).

When you switched to another user and then used `sudo -u dev`, that remembered password was gone and you had to re-enter the password.

The only solution is to remove the password from the identity file using

```
ssh-keygen -p -N "" -f /home/dev/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Afterwards you won't have to enter a password, neither as `dev` nor when using `sudo -u dev`.